# Difference between f[x] and f as arguments of functions

Tags: syntax, pure-function

I'm new to Mathematica and trying to better understand the syntax. In the documentation, the function `Limit` has the signature:

```
Limit[f[x], x -> x0]
```

whereas `FixedPoint` has:

```
FixedPoint[f, expr]
```

What is the difference between arguments of the form `f` and `f[x]`? I seem to be unable to pass pure functions in the case of `Limit`.

Comment: A pure function does not involve any variable names, so as you vary `x`, it will not change, and the limiting value will just be the pure function.

Comment: @Alan Is that the only difference between these cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference here is that `f` in `FixedPoint` is a function that (in the first iteration) gets applied to `expr` to form `f[expr]`. Then in the second iteration it gets applied again to form `f[f[expr]]` and `FixedPoint` checks if `f[f[expr]]` is the same as `f[expr]`.

You couldn't apply `f[x]` to `expr`, because you'd get `f[x][expr]` rather than `f[expr]`. In the second iteration you'd get `f[x][f[x][expr]]`. In most cases this would be meaningless. Technically, though, `f[x]` CAN be a function if you do something like:

```
f[x_] := Function[{y}, x + y]
```

In this case `f[1]` would be the "add one" operator that you can apply to other values:

```
f[1][2]
(* 3 *)
```

Now `Limit` on the other hand uses a substitution rule (or at least: the syntax of one). The best function to illustrate this with is `ReplaceAll` (or `/.` for short), which is a function that inspects an expression and replaces bits based on replacement rules you give. For example:

```
Clear[x];
{1, 2, 3, x} /. x -> 4
```

results in `{1, 2, 3, 4}`. The reason I first do `Clear[x]` is that this wouldn't work correctly if `x` had a value, so you have to be a bit careful when you use them. For example:

```
x = 1;
{1, 2, 3, x} /. x -> 4
```

which gives you `{4, 2, 3, 4}`. If you use `TracePrint[{1, 2, 3, x} /. x -> 4]`, you can see what happens: first `x` gets evaluated to 1 in the list; then `x` evaluates to 1 in the replacement rule and you end up with:

```
 {1,2,3,1} /. 1 -> 4
```

Hence the result.

There are other functions that do replacements like this (such as `Table`), except they use a slightly different mechanism and syntax. `Table` localizes its iterator, which you can spot from the syntax highlighting of `i` in the following example.

```
i = 2    
Table[i^2, {i, 1, 4}]
```

So I hope that these examples help you understand the differences between function application and value substitution.

Comment: Your examples made it a lot more clear. Could you summarize in one sentence what can be passed on as "f" and what as "f[x]"? I'm not sure I understand in general, even though you explained this particular case.

Comment: You use `f` whenever you need to pass on a function that gets applied repeatedly to arguments (e.g., `Map`, `Nest`, `Fold`, `Select`). In these cases you can use pure functions (i.e., `Function`). You use `f[x]` to pass on an expression into which `x` will be substituted with some other value. In this case, pure functions generally don't work.